# Global Descriptor Table and Local Descriptor Table relationship?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86, intel, gdt

[Protected-Mode Memory Management](http://www.internals.com/articles/protmode/protmode.htm)

I was going through segmentationof this link.

Both LDT are GDT are independent or dependent on each other ?

(TI bit (which is part of the selector) to decide which descriptor table should be used (the GDT or the currently active LDT) so i think is it independent)

From the figure
[image: GDTR-LDTR]

Also 
GDT (Global Descriptor Table) and is used mainly for holding descriptor entries of operating system segments.
 example kernel stack --code_section/data_section?

LDT 
The second type is known as the LDT (Local Descriptor Table) and contains entries of normal application segments (although not necessarily)
 user stack --code_section/data_section ?

it says the LDTR register contains the size and position of the currently active LDT in memory. 
Does that mean in context switch we save the LDTR value of each process in pcb of that process ?